# Woocommerce Membership - how to get all restricted content a user/membership has access to?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-memberships

Trying to totally customise the Woocommerce My Account page on a Membership site using Woo Memberships.

I am trying to write a custom block that fetches all the content a user has purchased access to via a membership. Is there a function I can use? I cant see anything in the docs.

Trying to do something like this

```
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Fetch active memberships for the current user
$args = array( 
    'status' => array( 'active', 'complimentary', 'pending' ),
);  
$active_memberships = wc_memberships_get_user_memberships( $user_id, $args );

if ( ! empty( $active_memberships ) ) {
    echo '<h3>Unlocked Content</h3>';
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach ( $active_memberships as $membership ) {
        // Get the plan ID for the current membership
        $plan_id = $membership->get_plan_id();

        // Retrieve content associated with the plan
        $content_posts = wc_memberships()->get_plan_content_restricted_posts( $plan_id );

        if ( ! empty( $content_posts ) ) {
            foreach ( $content_posts as $content_post ) {
                // Display the unlocked content to the user
                echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink( $content_post->ID ) . '">' . get_the_title( $content_post->ID ) . '</a></li>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li>No content unlocked for this membership.</li>';
        }
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    echo '<p>No active memberships found.</p>';
}
```

This is the plugin I am using.

https://woo.com/products/woocommerce-memberships/

Comment: I kindly remember that LLMs like ChatGPT are completely banned from question and answers…. Also, there are multiple different plugins handling Memberships for WooCommerce, so you should be more explicit.